# How to get focus on click, but keep it on mouse wheel in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, focus

If I do `this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::WheelFocus);` then if I were to mouse wheel above the widget, it would get focus. If I were to do `this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::ClickFocus);` but then mouse wheel causes it to lose focus, even if the pointer is in the same widget. So, how do I get focus on click, but keep it on mouse wheel?

Upon further investigation: the mouseWheelEvent is always processed after focus events. So trying to set a variable to remember whether this is due to a mouse wheel does not work. Furthermore, the reason given in the FocusReason is mouse in the case of a wheel or a click, so that doesnt help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick:

```
Foo::Foo(){
    this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::WheelFocus);
}

void Foo::focusInEvent( QFocusEvent *event ){
    if (!(QApplication::mouseButtons() & Qt::LeftButton)){
        this->clearFocus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[enum Qt::FocusPolicy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum)

```
This enum type defines the various policies a widget can have with respect to acquiring keyboard focus.
Constant            Value           Description
Qt::TabFocus        0x1             the widget accepts focus by tabbing.
Qt::ClickFocus      0x2             the widget accepts focus by clicking.
Qt::StrongFocus     TabFocus | 
                    ClickFocus | 
                    0x8     the widget accepts focus by both tabbing and clicking. On Mac OS X this will also be indicate that the widget accepts tab focus when in 'Text/List focus mode'.
Qt::WheelFocus      StrongFocus | 
                    0x4             like Qt::StrongFocus plus the widget accepts focus by using the mouse wheel.
Qt::NoFocus         0               the widget does not accept focus.
```

`Qt::WheelFocus` is made up of `StrongFocus` which is made up of `ClickFocus`, so you should just set WheelFocus to get all the previous ones.

Comment: The problem with WheelFocus is that it grabs focus when I mousewheel over the widget, which I dont want.